# iif else in Matrix Report SSRS

Tags: list, matrix, ssrs-2012

I am designing a Matrix report I want to compare each Matrix value in If condition 
for example

```
=IIF(FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!EndDate.value),"dd/MMM/yyyy") = "1/1/2155" OR FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!EndDate.value),"dd/MMM/yyyy") = "12/31/2154",(Fields!EndDate.value),"TillDate")
```

this expression is printing TillDate against every record. but i want to print TillDate in front of those records that they have EndDate "1/1/2115" OR "12/31/2154" and other records will show their actual EndDate

Comment: Don't you mean "dd/MM/yyyy"? Why are there 3 M's? Also, don't you need to write your dates as "01/01/2155" if you say the format is "dd/MM/yyyy"?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write out the values in a box or label to test your output.